# How to filter out a certain pattern in filter pyspark RDD

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a pyspark sc initialized.

```
instance = (data
          .filter(lambda x: len(x) != 0 )
          .filter(lambda x: ('%auth%login%' not in url)
          .map(lambda x: function(x))
          .reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
```

My goal is to filter out any url that has both **auth** and **login** keywords in it, but they could be in any position of a string.

In sql I could use %auth%login%,  % means any length of string.

How to do it in pyspark syntax easily?

Forgot to mention, there are 'auth' page I do not want to filter out, I only want to filter out auth when login is also in the string

I am not sure why this is flagged as dups, this is RDD not dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PySpark RDD filter method, you just need to make sure at least one of `login` or `auth` is NOT in the string, in Python code:

```
data.filter(lambda x: any(e not in x for e in ['login', 'auth']) ).collect()
```

Comment: this method won't work since I do want to retain some 'auth' pages, I only want to exclude when both keywords(auth and login) exist in the url. I will explore all method

Comment: @inuyashayolo, this will keep the urls containing `auth` if `login` does NOT exist at the same time. as I mentioned in my post. Any of the two does not exist which is basically to exclude only cases when both exist. please do test on some sample URLs to verify.

Comment: Or in another word, this condition means any of the following three: (1) `auth` does not exist, (2) `login` does not exist, (3) neither `auth` nor `login` exist.

Comment: just tested this part in python any(e not in x for e in ['login', 'auth']) . it works for mutual. I am not sure why this question is marked as dups since it is rdd not dataframe..Thank you @jxc

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using a dataframe, you are looking for [contains](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.contains):

```py
#url is the column name 
df = df.filter(~df.url.contains('auth') & ~df.url.contains('login'))
```

When you are working with a RDD, please have a look at the answer of [jxc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59941672/6664872).